# Ссылка при попытке ухода с сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я часто видел, что при попытке навести на крестик, сайт что-то предлагает. Как это реализовано?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё это работает так, что пользователь не обязательно наводит на крестик. Просто указатель мыши выходит за пределы документа, тогда вызывается ивент.

На чистом JS:

```
document.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event){
    alert('Стопэ!');
    // Любой другой код, вызывающий всплывающие окна, изменения дерева и т.д
});
```

Для jQuery можно делать так:

```
$(document).mouseleave(function(e){
    alert('Стопэ!');
    // Любой другой код, вызывающий всплывающие окна, изменения дерева и т.д
});
```

Единственное, не забывайте вешать куку о том, что пользователь уже пытался выйти, чтобы он не сошёл с ума :)